# What does "DataView is not marked as serializable in System.data" mean?

Tags: asp.net

When I store dataview in viewstate,.net shows the error "Dataview is not marked as serializable in system.data but when I store it in session, then it works perfectly?
What is the reason behind it?? Which are the other objects that are not marked as 
"serializable " ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the object you want to store ([DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx)) isn't marked with a [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Now, the reason you're getting this error with ViewState and not with Session is because the ViewState is *always* serialized but that's not necessarily true of Session. [In-Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) sessions are stored in the server's memory and require no serialization. [SQLServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) sessions have to be serialized for storage in a database.

So, anytime you want to store an object in the ViewState (or a *serialized* Session), it must be marked with a [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).