# ViewState list of objects c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

hallo iam getting this error message when the page is load,

Type 'messageBox' in Assembly 'App_Code.e9hyffkh, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

iam new in asp.net , and i can find what iam going worng!

heres my code:

```
public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string val = "";
public string data = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    val = "";
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ViewState["Messages"] = new List<messageBox>();
    }

}
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var messages = (List<messageBox>)ViewState["Messages"];

    if (text1.Text == "")
    {
        val = "נא הכנס שם";
    }
    else
    {
        messages.Add(text1.Text);
        val = "נוסף בהצלחה";
    }

    ListBox1.DataSource = messages;
    ListBox1.DataBind();
    ViewState["Messages"] = messages;
    data = messages.Count.ToString();

    text1.Text = "";


}
```

Comment: You can make List<messageBox>  to List<string> ? or you will need to mark the class messageBox as Serializable ..

Comment: What does the definition of messageBox Class look like please show that or add [Serializable] attribute to the top of that class

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928159/what-does-dataview-is-not-marked-as-serializable-in-system-data-mean/6928196#6928196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `[Serializable]` attribute on top of your `messageBox` class.

For reference: [SerializableAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx)

Comment: Answer would be improved if you told them why this was happening, many people are probably getting this exception because they don't realise that `ViewState` is calling a serialiser

Answer (score 2):

Add [Serializable] attrubute to your class not sure what your class looks like but see below for an example

```
[Serializable]
public class messageBox
{
   //other code / Fields related to the class goes below
}
```